# Chrome Changing tabs with scroll wheel

Tags: google-chrome

At work here we run Debian 8 with Chrome 42.  Because I work on a terminal I like my mouse because the scroll wheel is fast and touchy. When I go to chrome and mouse over any part not the web page any movement of the scroll wheel changes tabs which is very annoying.

This has been a somewhat annoying issue and I can't find any solution to it other than compiling chromium which is not an option(Networked images, any path I have write access to has execution disabled for obvious reasons. Even if I compiled it I could't start it.)

Am I missing something simple? My primary skill set is with Linux servers, not Linux desktop.

Comment: Looks like its a so called "Feature" in linux builds with no way to turn it off. Who designs this stuff and do they think? I guess no one thought "We should let people turn it off"
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1316